# How do I automatically add custom Macro Add-in to toolbar/ribbon after adding it in?

Tags: vba, excel, installation, add-in

How do I make adding in a custom Macro XLAM file as quick and simple as possible?

I have a macro saved as a XLAM file. I want other non-Excel-savvy people I work to be able to download the XLAM file, add it in like you would with any other add-in (e.g. Solver) and have it be a simple fool-proof process.

However, currently it involves adding it in, then going to the *file > options > customize ribbon > Macros > MyFancyMacroAddin*. Then clicking on the add in, then creating a new tab and sub group, to which the add-in can me moved from the left column to the right column. This is a long, error-prone process. Whenever I add in something like Solver, it just pops up in my toolbar after adding it in. However, it requires more steps it seems when doing a custom XLAM.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you generate a CustomUI.xml file for the XLAM?

Comment: No I did not, but I can research more into what that exactly means and how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: You can start [here](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Microsoft Excel Ribbon

To create create/edit the ribbon in Excel use [Custom UI Editor Tool](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/winfiles/OfficeCustomUIEditorSetup.zip). Here are some sources for creating the XML:

- [Microsoft Excel Automation](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win001.htm)
- [Microsoft Excel Automation Examples](https://github.com/Excel-projects)
- [Microsoft Office Ribbon XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/ribbon-xml?view=vs-2017)
- [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using Ribbon XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-ribbon-xml?view=vs-2017)

---

### To Install an Excel VBA Add-In

I use [XCOPY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/xcopy) in a .bat file for installing my .xlam files to user machines. I'll setup a folder on a network share e.g. `S:\Addins\MyFancyMacroAddin` and put the .xlam and .bat file in it. Then I distribute a shortcut to the .bat file to the end-users. It copies the file from the current directory to the [XLSTART](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/customize-how-excel-starts-6509b9af-2cc8-4fb6-9ef5-cf5f1d292c19) folder on their machine.

> You can click on the animation below to view it a bit easier.

#### Example:

[image: example]

#### Code:

```
@ECHO OFF

REM |--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
REM | Purpose:  Generic Excel Addin Install
REM |--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


REM
REM     /E   = Copies directories and sub-directories, including empty ones. Same as /S /E. May be used to modify /T. 
REM     /D:m-d-y = Copies files changed on or after the specified date. 
REM        If no date is given, copies only those files whose source time is newer than the destination time. 
REM     /K   = Copies attributes. Normal Xcopy will reset read-only attributes. 
REM     /Q   = Does not display file names while copying. 
REM     /R   = Overwrites read-only files. 
REM     /Y   = Suppresses prompting to confirm you want to overwrite an existing destination file. 
REM

REM Copy the install directory and sub-directories
REM echo f | XCOPY ".\MyFancyMacroAddin.xlam" "%AppData%\Microsoft\AddIns\MyFancyMacroAddin.xlam" /E /K /Q /R /Y /D
    echo f | XCOPY ".\MyFancyMacroAddin.xlam" "%AppData%\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\MyFancyMacroAddin.xlam" /E /K /Q /R /Y /D
REM echo f | XCOPY ".\MyFancyMacroAddin.xlam" "%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\MyFancyMacroAddin.xlam" /E /K /Q /R /Y /D
```

Comment: This is great. Thank you for your comment and your video. I am somewhat of a novice when it comes to advanced Macro operations like this so I will have to study your answer to see if I can get it to work for me. Thank you.

Comment: I was able to use the bat file to copy an XLAM from my AddIns folder to my XLSTART folder. However, when I start Excel, the new Macro is nowhere to be found. How can I get it to show up on the ribbon as yours does? Also, my Excel did not start automatically when I clicked the BAT file as yours did.

Comment: The ribbon in Excel is created with XML. The hyperlinks in the first part of my answer will show you how to create the ribbon. I used a shortcut key to start Excel.

Comment: I've been able to create my own custom ribbon with working macros using the custom UI editor, but my goal is to streamline the macro addition process for people who are not excel savvy. I like how clicking the BAT file simplifies the process of moving the file for them. But how do I simplify the addition of the macro to the ribbon process for them?

Comment: Do you want to add buttons to the ribbon with macros? The .bat will overwrite the file on end-user machines if you're talking about version control.

Comment: @hunterstevens were you able to get the ribbon up and running?

Comment: I would like to others to be able to add a working macro button to the ribbon as simply as possible. Which file does the .bat overwrite, and what do you mean by overwrite?

Comment: `/Y` in the .bat file will always copy the source file to the target. I'll post an example on GitHub for you with the ribbon in about 3 hours.

Comment: Direct link for file https://github.com/StackOverflow-projects/52615882/raw/master/Example.xlsm?raw=true

Comment: @auguid, Thank you for your help throughout this process. I will review your github link as soon as I can. I have already marked your answer as accepted and just upvoted all of your comments as a thank you.

Comment: No worries mate :)